# How do I only return values where a varchar column value does not equal a certain value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to calculate monthly sales but exclude certain sales that were from a specific customer.  Is this possible?

I have tried the below and it comes back with a `GROUP BY` error however I do not want to group by `PickupLocation_ContactName`, I want to have total monthly sales returned less Hurricanes customer orders.

I have read only access to the database.

```
SELECT 
    SUM (Price), 
    CONVERT(CHAR(7), PickupDateTime, 120) as Year_Month, 
    PickupLocation_ContactName
FROM 
    dbo.DeliveryRequests
WHERE 
    dbo.DeliveryRequests.PickupLocation_ContactName NOT LIKE 'Hurricanes%'
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(CHAR(7), PickupDateTime, 120)
ORDER BY 
    Year_Month
```

Comment: then just take PickupLocation_ContactName out of the select

Answer (score 3):

Any field in the SELECT part must be an aggregate or a field in the group by, and PickupLocation_ContactName is not in the GROUP BY. Add that to the GROUP BY, and your query should be fine.

```
SELECT SUM (Price), CONVERT(CHAR(7), PickupDateTime, 120) as Year_Month, PickupLocation_ContactName
    FROM dbo.DeliveryRequests
    WHERE dbo.DeliveryRequests.PickupLocation_ContactName NOT LIKE 'Hurricanes%'
    GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(7), PickupDateTime, 120), PickupLocation_ContactName
    ORDER BY Year_Month
```

Comment: Then it doesn't calculate total monthly sales - is there a way around that?

Answer (score 1):

I have created an example although it is in SYBASE ASE 15

please see below

```
create table DeliveryRequests 
(
Price int,
PickupLocation_ContactName varchar(10),
PickupDateTime date
)

insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (20 , "xxx" , "2015-06-23" )
insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (20 , "xxx" , "2015-06-24" )
insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (20 , "xxx" , "2015-06-25" )
insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (10 , "xxx" , "2015-05-23" )
insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (10 , "xxx" , "2015-05-24" )
insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (10 , "xxx" , "2015-05-25" )


insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (30 , "yyy" , "2015-06-23" )
insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (30 , "yyy" , "2015-06-24" )
insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (30 , "yyy" , "2015-06-25" )
insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (40 , "yyy" , "2015-05-23" )
insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (40 , "yyy" , "2015-05-24" )
insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (40 , "yyy" , "2015-05-25" )

insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (50 , "zzz" , "2015-06-23" )
insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (50 , "zzz" , "2015-06-24" )
insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (50 , "zzz" , "2015-06-25" )
insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (60 , "zzz" , "2015-05-23" )
insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (60 , "zzz" , "2015-05-24" )
insert into DeliveryRequests(Price,PickupLocation_ContactName,PickupDateTime)
values (60 , "zzz" , "2015-05-25" )

select sum(Price) sales, PickupLocation_ContactName,month(PickupDateTime) month
from DeliveryRequests where
PickupLocation_ContactName <> "zzz"
group by PickupLocation_ContactName, month(PickupDateTime)
```

RESULT ::

```
sales   PickupLocation_ContactName  month
30      xxx                         5
60      xxx                         6
90      yyy                         6
120     yyy                         5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use windowed version of `SUM` to get sum per Year/Month, i.e. total monthly sales, along with `PickupLocation_ContactName`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUM (Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Year_Month) AS SumPerYearMonth, 
    Year_Month,
    PickupLocation_ContactName
FROM 
    dbo.DeliveryRequests
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(7), PickupDateTime, 120)) AS x(Year_Month)
WHERE 
    dbo.DeliveryRequests.PickupLocation_ContactName NOT LIKE 'Hurricanes%'
ORDER BY Year_Month
```

This will give you `SumPerYearMonth` values repeated for every `PickupLocation_ContactName` within each `Year_Month` group.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c02f0/2)